# Symbolic non-commutative algebra

Tags: symbolic, algebra

Consider 3 non-commutative elements $A,B,C$ and we have the relation $CB=\alpha BC$.

I want to compute things like : $(A\otimes BC ) ( B \otimes B) = AB \otimes \alpha B^2C$

Is there any package doing this ?

Comment: Check the NCAlgebra package (I am not very familiar with it so I can't give an answer, but it's the biggest/oldest package dealing with such problems).

Comment: try www.github.com/NCAlgebra/NC

Comment: This package deals with non commutative algebra but it doesn't seem to treat  tensor products

Comment: You don't need a package. Just give Mathematica the rules for working with non-commutative multiplication and tensor product.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/noncommutative-tensor-product/259268#259268

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) for your noncommutative multiplication, we can encode your relation with:

```
B /: C . B := α B . C
```

Using [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) for your "⊗" operation, the output you want to get can then be obtained with:

```
KroneckerProduct[A, B.C].KroneckerProduct[B, B] //TensorExpand
```

> α KroneckerProduct[A.B, B.B.C]

Comment: What does this symbol "/:" do? (not easy to google such a thing)

Comment: @StevenSagona Look up "/:" in the help. It stands for either TagSet or TagSetDelayed.